Интеграция PostgreSQL с Qt5 C++
При попытке получить список доступных драйверов БД через:  qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers(); получаю список следующих: ("QSQLITE", "QODBC", "QODBC3")
Это стандартные, установленные вместе с Qt5 драйвера для некоторых баз данных. Моя задача - добавить драйвер для PostgreSQL. Я искал информацию, установил её с официального сайта. Узнал, что .dll нужно собрать из исходников в корневом пути PostgreSQL, у меня это: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\17
Как это сделать?
P.S Я установил Qt5 динамическую (5.15.15) через vcpkg, использую CMake для сборки проекта.

qt плагин для psql надо компилировать руками.

См. документацию

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html

Подскажите как это сделать
